# Increasing or Decreasing sequence in array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have an array of an element need to be print out according to following rule:

```
ai1 <= ai2 >= ai3 <= ai4 >= ai5 <= ai6
```

Input list =30, 12, 49, 6, 10, 50, 13

Expected Output = [10, 6, 30, 12, 49, 13, 50]

Please suggest me an approach to tackle this problem.
Here what I have tried.

```
      Arrays.sort(arr);

        for(i=2;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                int temp =arr[i-1];
                arr[i-1]=arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
```

Also help me finding time complexity and space complexity for the given approach.

Comment: Why is this tagged c++ while this code clearly isn't c++

Comment: You can do this in-place with a single pass of the array. That is, O(n) time complexity and O(1) extra space. I've answered a similar question before. Let me find it.

Comment: In your second example, the Expected Output does not meet the conditions. In that output, `ai1 >= ai2 <= ai3 ...`. But the condition you say it has to meet is `ai1 <= ai2 >= ai3 ...`. Also, if the expectation is that items be sorted and interleaved (i.e. `ai1 <= ai3 <= ai5` and `ai2 <= ai4 <= ai6`), then the only way to do it is to sort and interleave. But if you just need to meet the more general condition as specified in your original question, then the duplicate has the answer.

Comment: Wish I could downvote again, because the expected output in the updated question doesn't even match the rules. I read the rule of `ai1 <= ai2 >= ai3` to men that the 2nd value must be greater than the 1st and 3rd values, but that is *certainly* not true for `Expected Output = [10, 6, 30, 12, 49, 13, 50]` since 6 is **less than** both 10 and 30.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the array in ascending order.
2. for each **even** index, starting at i=2, swap `a[i]` and `a[i-1]`
3. Time and space complexity are the same as sorting

Comment: Here switch refers to swapping?

Comment: yes, sorry. I meant swap.

Comment: Not producing the result, check my edited code in the post

Comment: @Arya ```Output: 1 3 1 5 4 9 7 11 10 ```  fulfills your criteria of ```ai1 <= ai2 >= ai3 <= ai4 >= ai5 <= ai6```. Why would you need your stated expected output instead and how is that defined?

Comment: @Arya Why do you think the solution does not respect the rule? Please also avoid to modify the question after a solution has been provided

Answer (score 0):

The rule seems to be that values at odd indexes (1, 3, 5, ...) must be larger than values at the neighboring indexes, e.g. value at index 5 must be greater than value at indexes 4 and 6.

Easiest way to accomplish this is to put smallest values at even indexes and largest values at odd indexes. To split values into smallest and largest, sort the values first.

*Example:*

```
Input:    1,4,7,9,1,3,5,10,11

Sorted:   1,1,3,4,5,7,9,10,11
          └───────┘ └───────┘
          smallest   largest

            ↓   ↓   ↓    ↓     Odd indexes
Result:   1,7,1,9,3,10,4,11,5
          ↑   ↑   ↑    ↑    ↑  Even indexes
```

Doing it this way ensures that solution is correct, assume a solution is possible. E.g. if input is `1,1,1,1,2,2,2`, you still get valid solution (`1,2,1,2,1,2,1`), which a simple swap of neighboring values wouldn't.

I'll leave coding as an exercise for you to complete.

Comment: see the Expected Output detail

Comment: @Arya There are **many** solutions that will honors the given rules, so you cannot expect a specific output, unless you add more rules to define which solution is expected.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are multiple valid outputs for your problem, but I had the same idea @shuki avraham mentioned and @Andreas explained it in details.

So you sort it and you write the smallest then the largest number in array, and so on. And here is how you do it:

```
Arrays.sort(arr); 

for(int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
    System.out.print(arr[i] + " " + arr[n-i-1] + " ");
}

if(n % 2 == 1) System.out.print(arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehting like this would solve the purpose:

```
 int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 10, 11, 6, 0};
        //sort asc
        Arrays.sort(x);

        //swap at alternate, take care of odd/even length array
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length - 2;) {
            int temp = x[i + 1];
            x[i + 1] = x[i + 2];
            x[i + 2] = temp;
            i += 2;
            if (i >= x.length) {
                i--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
```